# com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: dev-view.rhines-dev.svc.cluster.local

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

Locally I am able to run the application but when I deploy it on GCP I get an error saying

```
 com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: custom-index.rhines-dev.svc.cluster.local
```

which is the host url I want to forward traffic to via zuul.

My service and routes have been registered.

```
zuul:
  ignoredPatterns:
    - /custom/**
  host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 4000
    socket-timeout-millis: 4000
  sensitiveHeaders:
  routes:
      serviceId: rhines
      path: /**
      url: ${GATEWAY_RHINES_ROUTE:http://localhost:8090}
```

gradle

```
// netflix-zuul
implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring- cloud-starter-netflix-zuul', version: '2.2.9.RELEASE'
```

I keep reading suggestions about eureka but I do not need a eureka server. I am building a gateway and I just want zuul to route my traffic.

Comment: Are these services deployed on kubernetes cluster?. If so, can you check the service(dev-view.rhines-dev.svc.cluster.local) is reachable(using curl)by doing ssh into some other pod in the same cluster. Does the url from GATEWAY_RHINES_ROUTE contains valid protocol?

Comment: @null yes I get a 200 response.

Comment: @null the answer is pretty simple.... add http:// to the url :( 
it works now. But with curl with and without it works.

Comment: I had a slight doubt on the protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the answer was pretty simple, add http:// to the URL. I am ashamed.